# javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException: Could not find resource for full path with RESTEasy and Wildfly 8.1.0.Final

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs, resteasy, wildfly-8

I am facing following problem. I have spent more than 3 days on this but cannot find a solution. Please guide me what I am doing wrong here. I am new to Resteasy with wildfly.

Here is the stacktrace

```
19:05:57,610 WARN  [org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler] (default task-14) failed to execute: javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException: Could not find resource for full path: http://localhost:8080/admin-ws/services/user/getUser
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.registry.ClassNode.match(ClassNode.java:73) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.8.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.registry.RootClassNode.match(RootClassNode.java:48) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.8.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodRegistry.getResourceInvoker(ResourceMethodRegistry.java:444) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.8.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getInvoker(SynchronousDispatcher.java:234) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.8.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:171) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.8.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:220) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.8.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.8.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:51) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.8.Final.jar:]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) [jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:61) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:113) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:56) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:45) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:61) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:70) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:240) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:227) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:73) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:146) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:177) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:727) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20]
```

Here is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
</web-app>
```

Here is the Application class.

```
package com.abc.admin.services.config;

import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

@ApplicationPath("/services")
public class WebConfig extends Application {

}
```

Here is the web service class.

```
package com.abc.admin.service;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import com.abc.commons.ws.entity.UserWsPojo;

@Path("/user")
public class UserResource implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6766329501327292893L;

    @GET
    @Path("/services/user/getUser")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public UserWsPojo getUser(String id) {
        UserWsPojo uwp = new UserWsPojo();
        uwp.setName("Aayush");
        uwp.setSurname("Devmurari");
        return uwp;
    }
}
```

Now in the above mentioned class I also tried to change the path of @Path with /getUser and also tried full path i.e. @Path("/services/user/getUser") none of these are working everytime I get the same error.

If you need to see anything  else please let me know. I will post it here.

Thanks for reading and helping.

P.S I have tried reading other questions on SO, documentation on RestEasy none of this helped me much. However I corrected my code while looking for the solution.

Based on the answers I did this too

```
@Path("/user")
public class UserResource implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6766329501327292893L;

    @GET
    @Path("/getUser")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public UserWsPojo getUser() {
        UserWsPojo uwp = new UserWsPojo();
        uwp.setName("Aayush");
        uwp.setSurname("Devmurari");
        return uwp;
    }
}
```

Other things are same as they are, still I am getting the same error.

```
22:15:58,489 WARN  [org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler] (default task-5) failed to execute: javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException: Could not find resource for full path: http://localhost:8080/admin-ws/services/user/getUsers
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.registry.ClassNode.match(ClassNode.java:73) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.8.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.registry.RootClassNode.match(RootClassNode.java:48) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.8.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodRegistry.getResourceInvoker(ResourceMethodRegistry.java:444) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.8.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getInvoker(SynchronousDispatcher.java:234) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.8.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:171) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.8.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:220) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.8.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.8.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:51) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.8.Final.jar:]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) [jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:61) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:113) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:56) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:45) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:61) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:70) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:240) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:227) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:73) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:146) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:177) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:727) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20]
```

Answer (score 14):

- **Base:**

  ```
  (1) http://localhost:8080/admin-ws  (I assume `admin-ws` is the app name)
  ```
- **`@ApplicationPath("/services")`** == append `/services` to **Base**

  ```
  (2) http://localhost:8080/admin-ws/services
  ```
- **`@Path("/user")`** == append `/user` to previous

  ```
  (3) http://localhost:8080/admin-ws/services/user
  ```
- **`@Path("/services/user/getUser")`** == append `/services/user/getUser` to previous

  ```
  (4) http://localhost:8080/admin-ws/services/user/services/user/getUser
             //This is the winner with your current set up
  ```
- **What you are using:**

  ```
  http://localhost:8080/admin-ws/services/user/getUser
  ```

  What's different?

### How it *Should* Look : to follow good REST (naming included) practices

```
@ApplicationPath("/services")
public class WebConfig extends Application {
}

@Path("/users")
public class UserResource implements Serializable {

    @Inject
    private UserService userService;

    @GET
    @Path("/{id}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public UserWsPojo getUser(@PathParam("id") String id) {
        UserWsPojo uwp = userService.getUserById(id);
        return uwp;
    }
}
```

**Access:**

```
http://localhost:8080/admin-ws/services/users/12344
                                       // some user id
```

Comment: Updated my question as you have explained here tried that too but still the same error. :( :(

Comment: Your `@Path` is `getUser` (no `s`). Your request is `getUsers` (with `s`)

Comment: Please also note the REST naming convention. `/users` for a collection resource (plural). We also make use of `{id}` path parameters for values that will vary

Comment: I have removed the extra "s" while trying your answer, please view my updated code in question, I have updated my question. Thanx for replying fast :)

Comment: pardon me for the url, i seem to have copied older stack trace. But I still get the same error. :)

Comment: Yes, I am using maven, I now the error has changed from resource not found to "Not Found". Do you want me to post the pom??

Comment: It looks fine, please try changing all the annotations to exactly like I have it and using this path `http://localhost:8080/admin-ws/services/users/12344`. Also you should clean and build your project. Look in the Wildfly `standalone/deployment` and delete the war and and unpackaged war, and deploy the newly clean and built war. I have no problems with the code I have posted

Comment: Thanks but I am already doing these steps before deploying to wildfly, alway clean and build, However I will try to change the annotation as you have, one more thing I also have the jboss-deployment-structure.xml to load the resteasy modules in wildfly.

Comment: Get rid of that. The JAX-RS module will automatically deploy with the `Application` class and `@ApplicationPath` annotation

Comment: Still the same error now the resource not found one :( :( Using java 8 is fine?? or its not yet compatible??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66223/discussion-between-peeskillet-and-samwise-gamgee).

Comment: @SamwiseGamgee See [the project as Github](https://github.com/psamsotha/admin-ws). You should be able to import it to Developer Studio, then run it as is. I tested it and it works fine. You should be able to access `http://localhost:8080/admin-ws/services/users/1234`. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Please let me know if/when you get the project. I'd like to delete it afterwards.

Comment: Hey there I follow this link http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/rest/resteasy/json-example-with-resteasy-jackson/ here if you can see sending a student is ok, I am doing the same in my code but its not working, i want to know why, I saw your code  in your code if your remove the parameter and simply return a UserPojo instead of building a response and sending it should work as per the link I specified.

Comment: Yes you don't need to build a response, but I do it out of preference as you can fine tune the response. Either way will be the same result for the body. I really don't get why you need me to test that link. Did you run my example? It works fine. Look from my code what you may be doing wrong. If you cannot run my example, then it may be something wrong that does not deal with the code. I ran it from Developer Studio

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66329/discussion-between-samwise-gamgee-and-peeskillet).

Comment: Please guide on  :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41314732/for-http-request-with-uri-resteasy-jpa-crud-resteasy-services-employeeservice

Answer (score 4):

I got the same issue when I tried with 3.0.11.Final

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
<artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
<version>3.0.11.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

but when I tried with another version it worked.

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
<artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
<version>3.0.4.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I expect, code should work with latest dependencies as well. Did someone able to run code with 3.0.11.Final or 3.0.16.Final ????

Answer (score 2):

Consolidating all the response and below code should work. Tested in tomcat 7.0.56, RESTEasy 3.0.10, Netbeans 8.0.2

**WebConfig.java:**

```
import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;
@ApplicationPath("/services")
public class WebConfig extends Application {
 // No methods defined inside
}
```

**SayHello.java:**

```
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
@Path("/greet")
public class SayHello {
 @GET
    @Path("/{username}")
    @Produces("text/html")
    public Response printMessage(@PathParam("username") String username) {
        return Response.status(200).entity("Hello " + username).build();
    }

}
```

**Netbeans generated web.xml: no change needed**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- With RESTEasy no web.xml configuration required-->
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
     version="3.0">
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

**URL to Your REST SERVICE:**

```
http://hostname:<port>/<yourappcontext>/services/greet/<enterusername>
```

**Expected Response**:

```
Hello <username>
```

**Netbeans generated POM.XML: (make sure to include resteasy-servlet-initializer dependency if using tomcat and version 2.3 or greater for maven-war-plugin)**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.easyrest</groupId>
    <artifactId>easyrest</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>easyrest</name>

    <properties>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <!-- Add POM dependencies -->
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>org.jboss.resteasy</id>
            <url>http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.10.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-servlet-initializer</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.10.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                            <silent>true</silent>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>6.0</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 2):

This works for all my services.

```html
This is a runtime exception indicating a resource requested by a client was not found on the server.
Add below entry into your web.xml :

<context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.resources</param-name>
        <param-value>com.org.abc.xyz.MainClassName</param-value>
</context-param>
```

You can specify fully qualified name of your JAX-RS resource class name you want to register.
If you have multiple classes entries, use comma delimiter.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem (javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException: Could not find resource for full path ...). Based on [this link](https://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/resteasy-hello-world-example/), the steps to solve the issue are below:

1) Set the application class:

```
/**
 * Application class
 */
package com.abc.admin.services.config;

import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

@ApplicationPath("/services") // the begining of the Webservice URL
public class WebConfig extends Application {
    private Set<Object> singletons = new HashSet<Object>();

    public WebConfig() {
        singletons.add(new UserResource());
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Object> getSingletons() {
        return singletons;
    }
}
```

2) Set the Resource class:

```
/**
 * Resource class
 */
package com.abc.admin.service;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import com.abc.commons.ws.entity.UserWsPojo;

@Path("/user")
public class UserResource implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6766329501327292893L;

    @GET
    // there is a URL concatenation to access the method (.../services/user/getUser)
    @Path("/getUser") 
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public UserWsPojo getUser(String id) {
        UserWsPojo uwp = new UserWsPojo();
        uwp.setName("Aayush");
        uwp.setSurname("Devmurari");
        return uwp;
    }
}
```

3) Set the web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>restContext</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix</param-name>
    <param-value>/rest</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher
    </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
        <param-value>com.abc.admin.services.config.WebConfig</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern> <!-- /* is not a comment, but part of the setting -->
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

4) Test the configuration in a browser:

http://localhost:8080/restContext/rest/services/user/getUser

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to say for sure, but one thing I see is that you are passing a parameter but not mapping any parameter in the URL. This would be more correct:

```
@GET
@Path("/getUser/{id}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public UserWsPojo getUser(@PathParam("id") String id) {
  // do things with stuff
}
```

And then the full URL would be /admin-ws/services/user/getUser/1 to get a user with ID 1.

Comment: I removed the parameter still I am getting the same error, I have updated my question please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

I've got same issue (NotFound). After debugging, it turned out that I missed the method. (@GET, @POST...) on the controller

```
@Path("/create")
public Response createObject(){
}
//correct
@GET // or @POST
@Path("/create")
public Response createObject(){
}
```