# javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException: Could not find resource for full path: with RESTEasy, Eclipse Luna and Tomcat 7

Tags: java, eclipse, rest, maven, resteasy

RESTEasy 3.0.9.Final
Eclipse Luna
Tomcat 7.0.59

I'm having the same issue as all the others who has asked the same question on here. I tried the solutions but none has worked for me so far.
When I go to type in the url to hit the webservice I get this error. 
Here is my service

Service.java

```
    package com.jjproj.hibernate.service;

import java.util.List;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import com.jjproj.hibernate.model.Employee1;
import com.jjproj.hibernate.model.EmployeeDao;



@Path("service")
public class Service {

    private EmployeeDao dao = new EmployeeDao();




    //GET Method to return JSON format of an employee
    @GET
    @Path("/getEmployees")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    public List<Employee1> getEmployees()
    {

        System.out.println("You made it in");
        return dao.getEmployees();
    }

}
```

This is my wrapper

RESTWrapper.java

```
package com.jjproj.hibernate.service;

import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;


@ApplicationPath("service")
public class RESTWrapper extends Application {

}
```

The path I am using is http://localhost:8080/HibEx1/service/getEmployees

There is nothing in my web.xml except displayname tag. 
This is a maven project

```
[http-bio-8080-exec-3] ERROR org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler - failed to execute
javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException: Could not find resource for full path: http://localhost:8080/HibEx1/service/getEmployees
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.registry.ClassNode.match(ClassNode.java:73)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.registry.RootClassNode.match(RootClassNode.java:48)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodRegistry.getResourceInvoker(ResourceMethodRegistry.java:444)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getInvoker(SynchronousDispatcher.java:234)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:171)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:220)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:51)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1074)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: [possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27297884/2587435)

Answer (score 4):

You are using `service` as `@ApplicationPath` of your Application *and* `@Path` of your ResourceClass. So you need to call http://localhost:8080/HibEx1/service/service/getEmployees or change one of the paths.

Comment: If it's a different problem you can open another question. If the original problem is solved you can accept the answer.