# Issue with resteasy and wildfly

Tags: java, rest, jboss, resteasy, wildfly-8

I have went through every other posts on SO, related to this but still not able to get an answer.I am having an ear file containing a war file. I had some libraries inside the war/WEB_INF/lib folder and when i deploy this everything is working fine. Now if i move the libraries to a module and add that module as a dependency in the jboss-deployment.xml its showing an error in the log like below and the service is not available.

```
2016-01-12 18:48:21,004 WARN  [default task-26]-[org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler] failed to execute: javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException: Could not find resource for full path: https://135.250.17.117:8443/webapps/rest/myservice
  at org.jboss.resteasy.core.registry.ClassNode.match(ClassNode.java:73)
  at org.jboss.resteasy.core.registry.RootClassNode.match(RootClassNode.java:48)
  at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodRegistry.getResourceInvoker(ResourceMethodRegistry.java:444)
  at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getInvoker(SynchronousDispatcher.java:234)
  at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:171)
  at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:220)
  at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56)
  at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:51)
  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
  at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:86)
  at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:130)
  at com.mycompany.axs.webapps.filters.LoginFilter.doFilter(LoginFilter.java:77)
  at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
  at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132)
  at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:85)
  at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
  at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
  at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
  at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
  at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
  at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
  at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
  at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationConstraintHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationConstraintHandler.java:51)
  at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
  at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
  at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.java:56)
  at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58)
  at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:70)
  at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76)
  at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
  at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
  at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
  at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
  at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:261)
  at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:248)
  at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:77)
  at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:167)
  at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:199)
  at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:761)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The products I am using are listed below

1) Wildfly 8.2.1.Final
2) Resteasy 3.0.10.Final
3) Resteasy Spring 3.0.10.Final

My module.xml below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="com.mycompany.axs.webapps">
    <resources>
           <resource-root path="com.mycompany.axs.webapps.utils-1_9.5-SNAPSHOT.jar"/>
            <resource-root path="hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.5.Final.jar"/>
            <resource-root path="hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar"/>
            <resource-root path="hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar"/>
            <resource-root path="jsr173_api-1.0.jar"/>
            <resource-root path="jsr305-1.3.9.jar"/>
            <resource-root path="jsr311-api-1.1.1.jar"/>
            <resource-root path="libthrift-0.9.2.jar"/>
            <resource-root path="log4j-1.2.17.jar"/>
            <resource-root path="lz4-1.2.0.jar"/>
            <resource-root path="mail-1.4.4.jar"/>
            <resource-root path="metrics-core-2.2.0.jar"/>
            <resource-root path="metrics-core-3.0.2.jar"/>
            <resource-root path="mimepull-1.6.jar"/>
            <resource-root path="netty-all-4.0.23.Final.jar"/>
            <resource-root path="netty-buffer-4.0.27.Final.jar"/>
            <resource-root path="netty-codec-4.0.27.Final.jar"/>
            <resource-root path="netty-common-4.0.27.Final.jar"/>
            <resource-root path="netty-handler-4.0.27.Final.jar"/>
            <resource-root path="netty-transport-4.0.27.Final.jar"/>
            <resource-root path="paranamer-2.5.2.jar"/>
            <resource-root path="protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar"/>
            <resource-root path="reflections-0.9.9-RC1.jar"/>
            <resource-root path="reporter-config-2.1.0.jar"/>
            <resource-root path="resteasy-jackson-provider-3.0.10.Final.jar"/>
            <resource-root path="resteasy-jaxb-provider-3.0.4.Final.jar"/>
            <resource-root path="resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.10.Final.jar"/>
            <resource-root path="resteasy-jettison-provider-3.0.10.Final.jar"/>
            <resource-root path="resteasy-multipart-provider-3.0.4.Final.jar"/>

    </resources>
    <dependencies>
        <module name="org.springframework" export="true"/>
        <module name="com.mycompany.axs.common.lib" export="true"/>
        <module name="org.jboss.as.web" export="true"/>
        <module name="org.codehaus.jackson.jackson-core-asl" export="true"/>
        <module name="org.codehaus.jackson.jackson-mapper-asl" export="true"/>
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

Please let me know what is the issue.

Comment: have you tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27295720/javax-ws-rs-notfoundexception-could-not-find-resource-for-full-path-with-restea

Comment: that one don't have an answer, still i did all the things mentioned. But nothing works.

Comment: It has several answers except then it doesn't have an accepted answer. In any case: always mention the versions of *all* products you use in your question.

Comment: @TT. updated the question with versions I am using. Please let me know if anything else is required.

Comment: Also include your `module.xml`

Comment: I am probably not experienced enough to say this, but I think you can't reference the `module.xml` in your `jboss-deployment.xml`. Can you read through [this link](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Class+Loading+in+WildFly) to see if this sheds some light on your issue?